# Using process substitution to merge mutiple PDF streams using cpdf from a (Laravel) PHP script

Tags: php, bash, shell, symfony, pdf

### Task

I'm generating 2 or 3 small pdfs during the course of a PDF script (Laravel application), and would like to merge them before returning them to the user.

After a lot of trials with various software options, I have settled on using ([cpdf](https://www.coherentpdf.com/)) as the program I want to use to merge them. (It is used for other pdf manipulation processes I do and has certain merging capabilities I am purposely leaving out of this question for simplicity)

I **REALLY** want to avoid having to manually code the need to save each pdf string as a temporary file, then merge the files and finally remove all the temporary files used.

### The Issue

[The cpdf options for merging](https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/cpdfmanualli1.html#x2-3000) do allow for input from STDIN, but as I have multiple input strings to send, I do not see how I can use this. The command also can output to STDOUT so things like this are possible:

`cpdf -stdin reverse -stdout` which would basically reverse the pages in a pdf document provided by STDIN and output on STDOUT

Instead the normal file merge command would look like this:
`cpdf -merge -i file1.pdf -i file2.pdf -o output.pdf`

This led me on a google path that arrived at using bash's [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst). Something like this I thought would be possible

`cpdf -merge -i <(echo $pdf1string) -i <(echo $pdf2string) -stdout`

I use [symfony's process component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#usage) when running shell commands from my script, and so that code above would look like this:

```php
$pdf1 = <pdfstring1>;
$pdf2 = <pdfstring2>;

$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process(
    [
        'cpdf',
        '-merge',
        '-i',
        "<(echo {$pdf1string})",
        '-i',
        "<(echo {$pdf2string})",
        '-stdout'
    ]
);

$process->run();

$output = $process->getOutput();
```

However this is where the problems all start to arise.

### Problems and Attempted Solutions

First of all because the pdf strings being passed into the symfony process are not escaped, they blow up the command with unmatched ' or ". I tried to get around this by base64 encoding the pdf string before passing it into the command and decoding it in the shell

```php
$pdf1 = base64_encode(<pdfstring1>);
$pdf2 = base64_encode(<pdfstring2>);

$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process(
    [
        'cpdf',
        '-merge',
        '-i',
        "<(echo {$pdf1string} | base64 --decode)",
        '-i',
        "<(echo {$pdf2string} | base64 --decode)",
        '-stdout'
    ]
);

$process->run();

$output = $process->getOutput();
```

But then that blew up because I discovered that the Symfony process component uses the `sh` shell and not `bash` by default....and I was trying to use a `bash` feature.

So I switched to trying this

```php
$pdf1 = base64_encode(<pdfstring1>);
$pdf2 = base64_encode(<pdfstring2>);

$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process(
    [
        '/bin/bash',
        '-c',
        "cpdf -merge -i <(echo {$pdf1string} | base64 --decode) -i <(echo {$pdfstring}| base64 --decode) -stdout",
    ]
);

$process->run();

$output = $process->getOutput();
```

Now THIS broke with an "Illegal seek" message which I think means that the cpdf program is trying to seek within the pipe file that is created with `bash` but that is not a seekable file. [stackoverflow answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164107/why-does-bash-process-substitution-not-work-with-some-commands)

Finally I read that `ZSH` shell has another substitution method using `=()` instead of `<()`. So I gave that a go:

```php
$pdf1 = base64_encode(<pdfstring1>);
$pdf2 = base64_encode(<pdfstring2>);

$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process(
    [
        '/bin/zsh',
        '-c',
        "cpdf -merge -i =(echo {$pdf1string} | base64 --decode) -i =(echo {$pdf2string} | base64 --decode) -stdout",
    ]
);

$process->run();

$output = $process->getOutput();
```

Finally it worked!! I got a merged pdf.

But it feels very complicated and messy, and I'm worried about the extra memory needed to base64 encode the string before it's sent to the shell.

### Requests

- Would anyone be able to suggest a more streamlined command line
  options to achieve what I am attempting to do?
- How would I pass the
  unescaped/non base 64 encoded PDF string to the shell and not have it
  blow it?
- Can you pass multiple stdin strings to a command in one go?
  (I think the answer to this is obviously no).

I appreciate you sticking through this long post!

Comment: Have you tried sending 2 PDFs consecutively on `stdin` like this `{ cat first.pdf; cat second.pdf; } | cpdf -merge > combined.pdf` Be sure to include all spaces and semi-colons.

Comment: The generated pdfs are originally NOT saved as files. They are generate and held in memory as variables and I do not want to save them to disk.

Therefore `{ cat first.pdf; cat second.pdf; }` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I was trying to establish whether 2 PDFs can be sent, one after the other, to the `stdin` of `cpdf`. Whether they come from disk or memory is another matter...